# Create path from javascript object property

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties, javascript-objects

Let's say I've got the following javascript object

```
var obj = {
            a:{
                b:"value",
                c:{
                    d:"value2"
                }
            }
        }
```

What function would, when input with the "d" object (for example, `function getPath(obj, d)`), output the "a.c.d" string? I've tried various things including [object-path](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path), but it doesn't seem to be designed for that

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"input with the "d" object"*? Please provide an example of such a function call. If you mean something like `path(obj.a.c.d)`, then there is no way to get the desired outcome (because all the function gets is the string value `"value2"`, it doesn't, and cannot, know about `obj`).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that? What if another property had a child 'd'? What if a parent is a 'd'?

Comment: How would this react to `obj = {d:{d:{d:{d:"val"}}}}` when asked for d? does it return `d`, `d.d`, `d.d.d` or `d.d.d.d`?

Comment: @NickA It should return `d.d.d.d` @Felix Kling Would it not be possible if you also input "obj"?

Comment: @user2950509: Sure, but it wasn't clear what the input was.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return path to value in JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32898401/218196)

Comment: I think this would only be possible if the original `obj` had a reference to the object `d` that you're searching for, ex.: `c:{ d }`, otherwise there could be ambiguous situations

Answer (score 3):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
function getPath(object, key) {

    function iter(o, p) {
        if (typeof o === 'object') {
            return Object.keys(o).some(function (k) {
                return iter(o[k], p.concat(k));
            });
        }
        if (p[p.length - 1] === key) {
            path = p;
            return true;
        }
    }

    var path = [];
    iter(object, []);
    return path.join('.');
}

console.log(getPath({ d: { d: { d: { d: 'val' } } } }, 'd'));
console.log(getPath({ a: { b: 'value', c: { d: 'value2' } } }, 'd'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a fair amount of fun making this one up, it generates a list of every possible path that can be made from the object and returns the longest one ending with the correct key, it returns an empty string of not found:

```js
function getPath(obj, key) {
    paths = []

    function getPaths(obj, path) {
        if (obj instanceof Object && !(obj instanceof Array)) {
            for (var k in obj){
                paths.push(path + "." + k)
                getPaths(obj[k], path + "." + k)
            }
        }
    }

    getPaths(obj, "")
    return paths.map(function(p) {
        return p.slice(p.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) == key ? p.slice(1) : ''
    }).sort(function(a, b) {return b.split(".").length - a.split(".").length;})[0];
}

var obj = { a:{ b:"value", c:{ d:"value2"}}};
console.log(getPath(obj, "b"))
console.log(getPath(obj, "c"))
console.log(getPath(obj, "d"))

var obj = { d:{ d:"value", d:{ d:"value2"}}};
console.log(getPath(obj, "d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the object using a recursive function, and save the path like :

```js
function getPath(object, keyValue, path) {
  for (var k in object) {
    if (k === keyValue) {
      return path + '.' + k;
    }
    else if (typeof object[k] === 'object') {
      return getPath(object[k], keyValue, path !== '' ? path + '.' + k : k);
    }
  }
}

var obj = {
    a:{
        b:"value",
        c:{
            d:"value2"
        }
    }
};

var path = getPath(obj, 'd', '');
console.log(path);
```

Comment: Does not work for test case `obj = {d:{d:{d:{d:"val"}}}}`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The function you want to use is `findLongestPath`:

```js
var obj = {
    a:{
        b:"value",
        c:{
            d:"value2"
        }
    }
};

function findAllPaths(obj, property, startString = '') {
  var pathStrings = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      pathStrings.push(...findAllPaths(obj[key], property, startString + key + '.'));
      return;
    }
    
    pathStrings.push(startString + key);
  });
  
  return pathStrings;
}

function findLongestPath(obj, property) {
  return findAllPaths(obj, property)
    .filter(str => str.split('').reverse().join('').slice(0, property.length) === property.split('').reverse().join(''))
    .reduce((longest, next) => longest.length >= next.length ? longest : next, '');
}

console.log(findLongestPath(obj, 'd'));
```

`findAllPaths` is a recursive function that iterates through the object and generates an array of all possible object paths. `findLongestPath` filters those strings to make sure the last property matches the property given, and then returns the longest of those.

Comment: Note that this will break if one of the properties is anything other than an object or a string.